# How to keep UIView box constrained to right side, with different size classes?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, ios-autolayout, size-classes

I have a UIView that I've constrained to the right-hand-side with the iPad Pro 9.7" size class, wR hR:

[image: Constrained to right-hand-side]

But when I switch to iPad Pro 12.9", wR, hR, the constraint becomes -256 (why isn't it still 0?):

[image: Not constrained anymore]

Comment: It is showing you that the view needs to be moved. You don't have all the constraints setup yet, so nothing will automatically get positioned. Once you have the rest of the constraints in there, it will move/size as it should.

Comment: If I move the view to where it suggests, the switch back to Pad Pro 9.7", the view is offset past the edge by +256.

Comment: Let me repeat... ***"Once you have the rest of the constraints in there, it will move/size as it should."***